# Android SQLite Database Unique constraint failed with composite primary key

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, unique-constraint, composite-primary-key

when I try to save in a table with a composite primary key, I get the error UNIQUE constraint failed when the same `Event.Player id` is used with the same `Event.Game id`, but since it is a 4-composite primary key it shouldn't give problems.

Create table code:

```
private static final String CREATE_TB_EVENT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_EVENT+" ( GAME INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        "PLAYER INTEGER NOT NULL, TYPE INTEGER NOT NULL, MINUTE INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ( GAME, PLAYER, TYPE, MINUTE ), " +
        "FOREIGN KEY ( GAME ) REFERENCES "+TABLE_GAME+" ( IDGAME ), " +
        "FOREIGN KEY ( PLAYER ) REFERENCES "+TABLE_PLAYER+" ( IDPLAYER ) )";
```

The error happens when first I update records in `TABLE_GAME`(the `IDGAME` is not touched), then I delete all the rows in `TABLE_EVENT` with that `IDGAME`:

`final String DELETE_EVENTS = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_EVENT+" WHERE GAME = "+game.getId();
db.execSQL(DELETE_EVENTS);`

And after that I call this method in which I get the unique constraint violated

```
public boolean saveEvents(ArrayList<Event> events, int gameID) {
    if(events == null)
        return false;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Log.v(TAG, getTableAsString(db, TABLE_EVENT));
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for(Event e : events) {
            cv.put("GAME",gameID);
            cv.put("PLAYER",e.getIdPlayer());
            cv.put("TYPE",e.getType());
            cv.put("MINUTE",e.getMinute());
            db.insert(TABLE_EVENT, null, cv);
            Log.v(TAG, getTableAsString(db, TABLE_EVENT));
        }
        db.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLiteException | NullPointerException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

The error: `Error inserting MINUTE=90 PLAYER=4 TYPE=2 GAME=54
UNIQUE constraint failed: Event.GAME, Event.PLAYER (code 1555)`

When I log in the method above to print the `TABLE_EVENT` I get:

```
Table Event: empty

Table Event: GAME: 54 PLAYER: 4 TYPE: 1 MINUTE: 23

Table Event: GAME: 54 PLAYER: 4 TYPE: 1 MINUTE: 23
             GAME: 54 PLAYER: 5 TYPE: 2 MINUTE: 45

Table Event: GAME: 54 PLAYER: 4 TYPE: 1 MINUTE: 23
             GAME: 54 PLAYER: 5 TYPE: 2 MINUTE: 45
             GAME: 54 PLAYER: 10 TYPE: 1 MINUTE: 23

Table Event: GAME: 54 PLAYER: 4 TYPE: 1 MINUTE: 23
             GAME: 54 PLAYER: 5 TYPE: 2 MINUTE: 45
             GAME: 54 PLAYER: 10 TYPE: 1 MINUTE: 23
```

As you see, the last two outputs are the same because it didn't add the new row with

`GAME=54 PLAYER=4 TYPE=2 MINUTE=90`

I tried in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/95b84/1) and everything is working as it should be

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you have a unique constrain on the table for the columns "game" and "player". I don't see it on your table definition though. Is it possible that the table already exists, and it has that added constrain?

Comment: Yes exactly, it looks like there's a definition UNIQUE(game,player) but there's not

Comment: Could you maybe try to drop the table, and recreate it again with the create code you posted? Or just check on sqlite if the table does have that particular constraint? Your create table executes only if the table does not exist, so maybe there's already a version of the table with that added constraint

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Due to the Auto Backup of Google there was an existing copy of my table and that's why it kept saying `UNIQUE constraint failed`. 
Solution was going in `Android Manifest` and set

```
allowBackup = "false"
```